# How to notify application user whenever i add something to remote database?

Tags: java, android

I have developed my first android application. 
What that application does: I update mysql database with new results on the website and the android application fetches the same data from mysql. I am using JSON.

What i want it to do: I want it to notify user that the results have been updated. It can bee a timely notification or the normal one. It does not matter. I just want the user to know about it as soon as i update database.

Code for your reference:
1) Java code that displays results inside the application.

```
  package in.thespl.spl.notifications;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
  import android.widget.ListAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class AllResultsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://mydomain.in/fetchresult.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "result";
private static final String TAG_PID = "rid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "rname";
private static final String TAG_INFO = "rinfo";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AllResultsActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllResultsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading results. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String info = c.getString(TAG_INFO);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_INFO, info);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
               // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                //       AllResultsActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               // startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllResultsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_INFO },
                        new int[] { R.id.rid, R.id.rname, R.id.rinfo});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
         });

       }

   }
  }
```

Any idea how to add a notification feature in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do that.

First way is to poll the server to ask for update. 
This solution isn't really efficient and lot of params are had to choose:
Time to update-> will affect battery and reactivity.

Second way is to use Google Cloud Messaging. It provides a solution to push data from server to user. It's really simple to implement. (took me some hours).
Android documentation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html
This second way optimizes battery and you could receive push even if your app is off.

Choose the way it's better for your needs.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: To use the second method, is it must to deploy the app to android market or i can use this feature even in the test phase? Because i am still testing the application and it's just for local use.

Comment: You can indeed use GCM without having the app on Google Play

Comment: Ok i am setting up GCM right now. I am stuck.
I am on linux. When i run ant war command it shows the following error


gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/build.xml:53: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.21/jre"